# Recording a Android Activity while it is not in the foreground

Tags: android, screen, video-capture, android-videoview, video-recording

My task is to show a demo of users data in video to the user.

To solve it my idea is to display data in animations and record all those animations in the background as a video.

I want to know if I is there anyway I can record the same even before displaying it and directly show to user as a video.(Without that activiy is not in onResume state or the user is not viewing the animations demo).

If there are any other options please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can record your actions.
In Android studio, go to **ANDROID MONITOR**, then you can see a *PLAY* icon on the left top,Second icon.
Press on that to start recording your actions on your Device.

Comment: hi I dont' think you got my question.I'm taliking about the app feature